# tcl:loop and extract with Regex

Tags: regex, tcl

I have large data and I want to extract two types of data based on two conditions. I wrote a tcl script to extract the data by using regex (newbie to regex).

I have used the following condition which works fine and produces part of the desired output:

```
if [regexp {\+ ([0-9.]+) 1 2.*- } $line -> time ] {
```

I'm using the variable time somewhere in the script. The above condition produces the following o/p(this is just a sample as the file is large):

```
+ 30.808352 1 2 tcp 40 ------- 30 6.7 2.30 81 2073
+ 30.808416 1 2 tcp 40 ------- 128 8.16 2.159 81 2069
+ 30.809513 1 2 tcp 40 ------- 156 12.19 2.187 1 2077
+ 30.809641 1 2 tcp 80 ------- 156 12.19 2.187 1 2078
+ 30.809878 1 2 tcp 40 ------- 151 7.18 2.182 41 2079
+ 30.813096 1 2 tcp 40 ------- 161 9.20 2.192 0 2083
+ 30.813352 1 2 tcp 40 ------- 157 13.19 2.188 1 2085
+ 30.81348 1 2 tcp 80 ------- 157 13.19 2.188 1 2086
+ 30.815362 1 2 tcp 40 ------- 148 12.18 2.179 41 2088
+ 30.815426 1 2 tcp 40 ------- 148 5.9 2.179 41 2089
+ 30.818096 1 2 tcp 40 ------- 162 10.20 2.193 0 2091
+ 30.818544 1 2 tcp 40 ------- 158 3.78 2.189 1 2093
+ 30.818672 1 2 tcp 80 ------- 158 14.19 2.189 1 2094
+ 30.820657 1 2 tcp 40 ------- 153 9.19 2.184 41 2096
+ 30.821579 1 2 tcp 40 ------- 154 10.19 2.185 41 2097
```

Then, inside the above if condition, I want check the 9th column :

```
//condition 1
if (9th between [3-6].*) ( such as 3.78,6.7, 5.9)
```

The second condition is :

```
  //condition 2
if (9th between [7-14].*) ( such as 14.19,12.18,10.19, 9.19,.....)
```

I'm struggling with two conditions above. I tried the following, I didn't get an error, however, no matching occurred !!

```
condition 1:
if [regexp {\+ ([0-9.]+) 1 2.*-* ([3-9])\..*/ } $line ] {
```

I know I'm repeating part of the main if condition, becuase I don't know how to skip the columns !!!

```
condition 2:
 if [regexp {\+ ([0-9.]+) 1 2.*-* ([7-9]|1[0-4])\..*/} $line ] {
```

Any suggestions !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

match 7-14 `\+ ([0-9.]+) 1 2.*- \d+\s(?:[7-9]|1[0-4])`  [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/gD9pJ1)
match 3-6  `\+ ([0-9.]+) 1 2.*- \d+\s[3-6]` [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/uE6cY2)

Comment: Nothing is printed !! the condition is not true !! Maybe if you put the full condition

Comment: @SimpleNEasy, I have attached links to Demo's

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you split on space? You can achieve pretty much the same outcome using a few more lines. It will be readable and can people will understand the code better:

```
if [regexp {\+ ([0-9.]+) 1 2.*- } $line -> time] {
    set elements [split $line " "] ;# You can actually omit the " " in this case
    set 9th [lindex $elements 8]

    # Condition 1
    if {$9th >= 3 && $9th < 7} { do something }

    # Condition 2
    if {$9th >= 7 && $9th < 15} { do something }
}
```

Comment: A matter of style: I find it more readable this way `{3 <= $9th && $9th < 7}` and `{7 <= $9th && $9th < 15}`

Comment: @glennjackman Oh, I think I know what you mean. It's a bit more like the math display of `3 <= x < 7` right?

Comment: @Jerry Your are absolutely right. This is so readable and easy for later on change.